# Informatica Developer(IDQ) stats

Tags: informatica, data-quality

How can we capture the mapping stats like mapping name ,Source rows,Target rows,Start time,End time in informatica developer(IDQ) tool into a table

Answer (score 0):

You can see the mapping stat under `Admin Console > Monitor > Execution Statistics > DIS name > Ad Hoc Jobs/Specific application`